# SSRS Optional Date Parameter extract no rows if null

Tags: reporting-services, visual-studio-2019, ssrs-2008-r2

I have a strange problem with a simple report in SSRS 2008.

my dataset looks like the follwing:

| ID | customer | CreationDate | Note |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | AAA | 10/20/2022 | first order |
| 2 | BBB | 10/22/2022 | second order |
| 3 | VVV | 10/23/2022 | ok |
| 4 | XYZ | 10/19/2022 | changed |
| 5 | AAA | 10/25/2022 | delivered |

In my report I have only a Table with all those columns and two parameters: **CreationDateFROM** and **CreationDateTO**.
Both parameters are very simple:

On the *General* tab we have

- Data Type: ***Date/Time***
- Allow Null value: ***SELECTED***
- Allow multiple Value: ***UNSELECTED***

Available Values: ***NONE***
Default Values: ***NONE***

The filter is inside the Dataset (tab *Filters*) and not inside the source Query.

Now, when I run the report these 2 parameters have the checkbox NULL selected, but the report returns NO ROWS.

Only if I activate the parameters and select some dates, the report works like a charm.

I need to have these paramters OPTIONAL because in the future probably I'm going to insert other parameters (like customer, ID ...)

there is a way to make this report work, keeping these parameters inside the report? I know that if I move those filters in teh query, it works but I have to keep them inside ther report.

thank you in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are a couple of ways to do this.

You can either set the default dates to some values outside your actual date ranges (e.g. 1st Jan 1900 and 1st Jan 9999) and then turn off the 'Allow Null' option.

The other way would be to change the expression in the dataset filter.

Assuming your 'from' filter says something like .

CreationDate >= @CreationDateFrom

Then change the filer `value` expression to this for the 'from' filter

```
=IIF(Parameters!CreationDateFrom.Value Is Nothing, DATESERIAL(1900, 1,1), Parameters!CreationDateFrom.Value )
```

And this for the 'To' filter

```
=IIF(Parameters!CreationDateTo.Value Is Nothing, DATESERIAL(9999, 1,1), Parameters!CreationDateTo.Value )
```

All this does is pass in 1900-01-01 if the from date is null and 9999-01-01 if the to date is null.